# SQL Server Management Studio show view designer without connection

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio, I want to see the designer for views that has 4 panes, But I want to see that without connection.

I know that I should connect to a server and select a database then I can show it by creating a new view or by editing an existing table.

similar to new query window that can be shown by file-new-menu or by Ctrl + N without connection

I have a database on a server with a lot of other databases (about 500), when I connect to the server and open the databases node it takes a lot of time (about 5 min) to show the list, then I can go to my database and create a view by design. I simply want to show the designer first and like query window ask me the connection and create my view.

[image: View Designer]

Comment: So.... what's the question?

Comment: what would be the point? Without a connection you can't create or modify a view anyway

Comment: Like "New Query" I can write code then connect to server

Comment: so? It would surely make no difference if you connected first and then wrote it. And if that _wasn't_ possible, and you still wanted to do so before connecting, you could just use another text editor. Anyway, it ought to be fairly obvious that the reason you can't do the "new view" without a connection is that the first thing the designer does is ask you what tables etc. you want to include in the design. Therefore, without a connection, it can't determine the database, and therefore can't list any items for you.

Comment: Of course, you can still make a view very simply in the "new query" window by simply writing it by hand. Although, without a connection, use lose the benefit of intellisense, and you can't use the designer either.

Comment: I have a database on a server with a lot of other databases (about 500), when I connect to the server and open the databases node it takes a lot of time (about 5 min) to show the list, then I can go to my database and create a view by design. I simply want to show the designer first and like query window ask me the connection and create my view.

Comment: *Views* are *database objects* just like tables and stored procedures. You can't create or work with them if you don't have access to their metadata and definition. If you want to work disconnected, use SSDT

Comment: Why not just learn to write your views without using that awful view designer?

Comment: Designing any database object offline is a snap with the [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). It's the closest thing you can have to a live database without actually having a live database, it keeps designer view and scripts in sync seamlessly, and it can even find references to any object even if obscured by things like `SELECT *`. It can also package your changes for later deployment on live. If it was legal for me to marry it, I probably would. Conversely, I never use the SSMS designers.

Comment: "I simply want to show the designer first and like query window ask me the connection and create my view." Well, it would still take 5 mins to connect after that, because in SSMS you still have to connect to the whole server, not just one database. So it wouldn't make any difference. If you want to avoid the connection time and have genuine offline working, use a tool like SSDT as suggested already.

Comment: the direct connection to database is fast. but it is 5 min to list databases in smss that is a waste.

Comment: I agree. But it's a generic server management tool, it doesn't focus on a specific database. It's used by people who administer the entire server at once. That's just the way it works. If you don't like it, maybe find a tool that lets you make a specific connection.